# How to get Windows-1252 character values in c++?

Tags: c++, extended-ascii

I have a weird input file with all kinds of control characters like nulls. I want to remove all control characters from this Windows-1252 encoded text file, but if you do this:

```
std::string test="tést";
for (int i=0;i<test.length();i++)
{
     if (test[i]<32) test[i]=32; // change all control characters into spaces
}
```

It will change the é into a space as well.

So if you have a string like this, encoded in Windows-1252:

```
std::string test="tést";
```

The hex values would be:

```
t  é  s  t
74 E9 73 74
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

test[0] would equal to decimal 116 (=0x74), but apparently with é/0xE9, test[1] does not equal the decimal value 233.

So how can you recognize that é properly?

Comment: `It will change the é into a space as well.` no it won't, because as you posted, the hex value of é is way above 32. Post something that actually reproduces the problem, don't describe your code. There's nothing special about Latin1/Windows-1252. Post something that someone else can take and execute on their own machine and get the result you describe, without having to add missing code or make comparisons by hand.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it can be a negative value deppending on the circumstances.

Comment: @anastaciu no, because a `char` isn't a number. It's sometimes treated as an unsigned byte value, which can lead to all sorts of weird bugs but C++ discourages this C-style usage. That's why one should compare chars with chars, not numbers. `32` isn't `' '`.

Comment: At the very least compare against the space character, `' '`, not the ASCII value: `if (test[i]<' ')`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I agree, but it's likely what's happening in the loop when it's compared with an `int`

Comment: In 2021, use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`32` is a signed integer, comparing the `char` with the signed integer is performed by the compiler as signed: E9 (-23)<32 which return true.

Using an unsigned literal of `32`, that is `32u`makes the comparison to be performed on unsigned values: E9 (233) < 32 which return false.

Replace :

```
if (test[i]<32) test[i]=32;
```

By:

```
if (test[i]<32u) test[i]=32u;
```

And you should get the expected result.

Test this here:
https://onlinegdb.com/BJ8tj0kbd

Note: you can check that `char` is signed with the following code:

```
#include <limits>
...
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed << std::endl;
```

Comment: what does the 'u' mean?

Comment: `u` indicates to the compiler that the value is a literal of type `unsigned int`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal
(Note: you can define your own custom literal suffixes.)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (test[i]<32)
```

to

```
if (test[i] >= 0 && test[i] < 32)
```

chars are often signed types and `0xE9` is a negative value in an eight bit integer.